# Config Azure application proxy using the graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, microsoft-graph-api, azure-function-app-proxy

I'm trying to automate the Application Proxy configuration. I can create applications, and service principals and configure permission. But I can't find a way to configure the app proxy. I found this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-proxy-configure-api?tabs=http but it uses the beta version.

Are there any endpoints in the Graph API in the release version that I can use to configure app proxy or when is MS going to release the beta version?

As I can see the Azure portal uses the `https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api` API to configure the app proxy. Can I use this API in my automated process? If so, how can I obtain a token for this API?

I found that I can obtain a token using `az account get-access-token --subscription $subscription --resource 74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6` but it doesn't work for me because I have to use [oauth authorization-code-flow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow). Is there any chance to use this `https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api` API?

I found following endpoint as well but still I'm not going to pass the client username and password through my APP.
`POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenatId}}/oauth2/token`

```
resource:74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6
grant_type:password
username:{{username}}
password:{{password}}
```

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hF7vn.png)

[Connected question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1159835/configure-application-proxy-using-the-microsoft-gr)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the document as the Application Proxy configuration is only supported in Beta version, you could a feature for the same for this feature to be available in the V1 release as well.

Raise a feature request here:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Comment: Thanks. I added request here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/config-azure-application-proxy-using-the-graph-api/idi-p/3722448#M1559